# How do I add a commercial coffee maker to my fridge's water line?

Tags: plumbing

I tried tapping into the ice maker feed, but it doesn't seem to be working.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just how did you try to do this? Was it on a thick 1/4” copper line with a cheap saddle valve? , take the tour of the site and learn how and what to ask if you want a good answer.

Comment: I tapped into the 1/4" plastic feed from the bottom to the ice maker using a T, but the coffee maker doesnt seem to be getting water, eventhough the ice maker does.

Comment: @ScottThompson Maybe take a picture of what you tapped into. It sounds like it's inside the appliance (and perhaps *after* the valve that makes ice)? I'd expect the T to be outside of the appliance entirely.

Comment: It was the exposed line coming from the bottom of the fridge.  There was a coupler already in place so I swapped it with a T, but the water doesnt flow to the coffee maker.

https://postimg.cc/gallery/1pgkchg3m/

Comment: you probably have water pouring onto the floor everytime the icemaker fills the tray

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's typically a solenoid valve right down at the bottom where the supply line from your house connects to the fridge, and this valve is activated by the ice maker when it needs more water.

Unfortunately, you've tapped in half-way up the back of the fridge - *after* the solenoid valve - so as a result, your coffee machine is only going to receive water for the brief period that the ice-maker in your fridge refills in between ice-making cycles.

You need to put that coupler back where you found it and instead find a way to tap into the water line which supplies your fridge from the wall.

Comment: That's what I figured.  It needs a constant feed of water.  Makes sense.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Wow , I have seen folks use saddles on 1/4 but never try to tap the fridge line.  Good catch @brahns+